# .map(parseInt) con resultados extraños

Tags: javascript, map, parsear

Me encontre con esto resolviendo un problema... Era un arreglo algo asi...

arr = `[1.5,2,11.4,22,3,5,2]`

Probe: `arr.map(parseInt)`== `[1, NaN, 3, 8, 3, NaN, 2]`

Me salto la curiosidad...

analizando un poco el resultado(solo las primeras cifras) comprobe que el primer numero lo convierte efectivamente a `number` mi entero esperado... pero el segundo resultado siempre regresa **NaN** asi inserte el mismo numero(`[1,1]==[1,NaN]`).. y el 3ro un 3?? luego segui probando cosas..

`[1,2,4]` == `[1, NaN, NaN]` pero.. `[1,2,11]`== `[1, NaN, 3]`??? me convirtio el 3 en 11?? tiene que ver algo con el que ya use el 1...

Mas cosas si el arreglo contiene dos `string` consecutivos al inicio no me regresa nada ej: `['1.5','2',22]` ==
pero... `['1.5',2,22,3,5,2]` == `[ 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2 ]` ?????
si se analizan todos los resultados devueltos en los ejemplos se siguen encontrando cosas raras como cambios de numeros `NaN` alternados en dependencia de los numeros anteriores del arreglo.. Me parecio interesante compartir esto, estoy invetigando pq sucede.. si alguien ya lo sabe y me puede sacar de las dudas se lo agradeceria..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los parametros pasados por el [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) son `(currentValue, index, array)`

Y los parametros que recibe [.parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) son `(string, base)`

Por lo que sabiendo los parámetros de cada uno se puede intuir el problema,
El `.map(parseInt)` es igual a `.map(parseInt(currentValue, index, array))`

Y como `parseInt` solo espera 2 parámetros el 3 lo ignora por lo que `parseInt(string, base, array)`sería igual a `parseInt(string, base)`

Cuando realizas:

```
[1.5,2,11.4,22,3,5,2].map(parseInt);
```

Realmente se ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
parseInt('1.5', 0, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//Parsea 1 con base 10 (base 0 es ignorado y toma el valor por defecto)

parseInt('2', 1, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//Base 1 es incorrecto, con lo que devuelve NaN

parseInt('11.4', 2, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//Parsea 11 en base 2, que es 3 en decimal

parseInt('22', 3, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//parsea 22 en base 3, que es 8

parseInt('3', 4, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//parsea 3 en base 4

parseInt('5', 5, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//5 en base 5 no se puede parsear, NaN

parseInt('2', 6, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);
//2 en base 6
```

Tu código debería de ser:

```
[1.5,2,11.4,22,3,5,2].map(e=>parseInt(e));
```

---

Una versión mas extendida de esta pregunta/respuesta:

**[Why ['1', '7', '11'].map(parseInt) returns [1, NaN, 3] in Javascript](https://medium.com/dailyjs/parseint-mystery-7c4368ef7b21)**

---

**Respecto al comentario:**

Como bien comentas lo mas intuitivo es que `parseInt('11.4', 2, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);` o lo que es lo mismo `parseInt('11.4', 2)` el resultado sea `NaN` ya que `11.4` no es un numero factible para base 2.

Parece que en estos casos parsea todo lo que puede hasta que se encuentra con un character que no sea `0` o `1`:

```
parseInt("11asd",2); // Output: 3
parseInt("asd11",2); // Output: NaN
parseInt("11asd1",2); // Output: 3 (aun que tenga otro 1, ya es ignorado)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder x3k_js :) .. estoy claro que map(parseInt) no funciona.. mis dudas son respecto a los resultados que me regresa.. no sabia que en el interior lo que hacia era `parseInt('11.4', 2, [1, 2, 11, 22, 3, 5, 2]);` si es asi igual no entiendo pq me regresa estos resultados no deberia ser entonces [11, 2, NaN] ? pq me cambia los valores y pq con dos string regresa ''

Answer (score 1):

Como bien dice @x3k_js, lo que ocurre es que estas pasando el índice del elemento como base del `parseInt` la prueba sería:

```js
const arr = ['1.5',2,22,3,5,2];

const res = arr.map(argumentos);

function argumentos(...args){//<-- Asi se ejecutaría parseInt()
    console.log(args);
}
```

El parámetro base del `parseInt` es la base en la que está expresado el número que se pasa por parámetro, no el resultado y esta debe ser entre 2 y 36. Fuera de estos valores, se asume que es base 10 si el string no comienza ni con "0x" ni con "0" o es `undefined`, 1 quizá debería retornar base 10 pero al parecer se ejecuta como `true`, entonces no reconoce nungún símbolo, lo que da `NaN`.

Entonces lo que ocurre es que si ponemos supongamos base 3 significa que el número que pasamos por parámetro tiene que formarse con los digitos 0, 1, 2. Sino es `NaN`. Ejemplos:

```js
console.log(parseInt("1010",2));//< -- parámetro en base 2 
console.log(parseInt("2020",3));//< -- parámetro en base 3
console.log(parseInt("FA0",16));//< -- parámetro en base 16


console.log(parseInt("2020",2));//< -- el simbolo 2 no es base 2 
console.log(parseInt("4040",3));//< -- el simbolo 4 no es base 3
console.log(parseInt("Z00",16));//< -- el simbolo Z no es base 16
```

Entonces el comportamiento extraño que tienes es fundamentalmente porque se pasan símbolos que no estan dentro de la base que se especifica.

- '1.5' base 0 se entiende base 10
- 2 base 1 es siempre `NaN`
- 22 base 2 solo usa los simbolos 0,1 entonces `NaN`
- 3 base 3 solo usa 0,1,2 entonces `NaN`
- 5 base 4 solo usa 0,1,2,3 entonces `NaN`
- 2 base 5 usa 0,1,2,3,4 retorna 2 que es 2 también en base 5